# Qt LineEdit boundires

Tags: c++, qt, custom-widgets

I have a `QLineEdit` which I have place a `QPixmap` on and at the end of the `LineEdit`. Is there a way where I can tell the `LineEdit` where to consider the end of the widget so that text is not drawn on top of the picutre?

All good the answer is `setTextMargins()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use QLineEdit [StyleSheet](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet.html) property.

```
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The LineEdit is a rectangular box - set its size correctly and everything should be fine, otherwise you might want to recheck your layouting.